# Matching all non whitespace characters after a string in Regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match all the non whitespace characters after a string in Regex. In this example, I want to match "b" without the whitespaces and the slashes around it:

```
      a:     /b/
```

I tried using `(?<=a:)([^\s\/]+)` but it doesn't work.

Comment: `a:\s*\/\K[^\s\/]+` or `a:\s*\/([^\s\/]+)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to account for `/` before `b`, not just for whitespace.

You may use a `\K` based regex (if your regex flavor is PCRE/Onigmo/Boost):

```
a:\s*\/\K[^\s\/]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nCInbu/1).

Also, if you are using a regex engine that supports unknown width lookbehind patterns, you may use

```
(?<=a:\s*\/)[^\s\/]+
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nCInbu/3).

Else, you need to *capture* your substring with parentheses:

```
a:\s*\/([^\s\/]+)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nCInbu/2).

**Details**

- `a:` - a `a:` string
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\/` - a `/` char
- `\K` - a match reset operator
- `[^\s\/]+` - 1+ chars other than whitespace and `/`.